# Firebase_compact_app_default.auth is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am trying to set up authentication with firebase to enable login and signup functions to run through a firebase backend.

These are the exact steps I have followed:

1. Installed the firebase package `npm install firebase`
2. Created a firebase project
3. Initialized firebase in React
4. Added firebase authentication to React

However, I am getting this error when I run my app now:

```
firebase_compat_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.auth is not a function
TypeError: firebase_compat_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.auth is not a function
    at ContextProvider
```

This is what I have in my 'root/home' page:

```
const Timeline = () => {
  const { user, setUser, auth } = useContext(Context);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setUser(user);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
        <Navbar/>
        <LoginModal/>
        <SignupModal/>
    </>
  );
};
export default Timeline;
```

I am using Context API to pass down props:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
...
export const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    ...
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const auth = firebase.auth();

    const handleSignIn = async (email, password) => {
        try {
          await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
    };
    
    const handleSignUp = async (email, password) => {
        try {
          await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
    };
    
    const handleSignOut = async () => {
        try {
          await auth.signOut();
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
    };
    ...
```

This is what I have in LoginModal (the modal that pops with a login form):

```
const LoginModal = () => {
  const { loginModal, setLoginModal, 
        handleSignIn, handleSignUp, 
        handleSignOut } = useContext(Context);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  ...
  return (
      <Modal 
        title="Login" 
        open={loginModal}
        closable='true'
        closeIcon={<CloseCircleOutlined onClick={()=>setLoginModal(false)}/>}
        footer={null} >
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='auth-form'>
      <label className='auth-label'>
        Email:
        <input
          type="email"
          value={email}
          className='auth-input'
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <label className='auth-label'>
        Password:
        <input
          type="password"
          value={password}
          className='auth-input'
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <button type="submit" className="auth-button" disabled={!email || !password} onClick={handleSignIn(email, password)}>Submit</button>
    </form>
      </Modal>
  );
};
```

export default LoginModal;

When I try to change my firebase import in Context to `import firebase from 'firebase/app';` , I instead get the error:

```
export 'default' (imported as 'firebase') was not found in 'firebase/app' (possible exports: FirebaseError, SDK_VERSION, _DEFAULT_ENTRY_NAME, _addComponent, _addOrOverwriteComponent, _apps, _clearComponents, _components, _getProvider, _registerComponent, _removeServiceInstance, deleteApp, getApp, getApps, initializeApp, onLog, registerVersion, setLogLevel)
```

I changed this to `import firebase from firebase/compact/app` based on an accepted solution I found to a somewhat similar question on SO. Would appreciate any help